# Is there a way to remove the unwanted imports in python when object got serialzied

Tags: python, serialization, python-import, pickle

Imagine I have `a.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
class A:
    name = "Class A"
```

`dump.py`:

```
import pickle
from a import A

a = A()

with open("a.pickled", "wb") as f:
    f.write(pickle.dump(a))
```

`load.py`:

```
import pickle
with open("a.pickled", "rb") as f:
    a = pickle.load(f.read())
```

When python `pickles` the object `a`, it actually also pulls in the `tensorflow`. As a result, when the object got deserialized in `load.py`, it imports `tensorflow` and brings in a bunch of expensive initialization related to `tensorflow`. I am wondering if we can remove the unwanted `tensorflow`  import in `dump.py` without modifying `a.py`

I tried something like this in `dumpy.py`, but this doesn't work for me:

```
import pickle
from a import A
# Delete tensorflow related import from cache 
import sys
names = [name for name in sys.modules.keys() if "tensorflow" in name]
for name in names:
    del sys.modules[name]

a = A()

with open("a.pickled", "wb") as f:
    f.write(pickle.dump(a))
```